# Many to Many relationships - data model

Tags: orm, many-to-many, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I have a case where a product can have different prices per country. I am not sure of the best way to design this, which would help me maintain ORM relationships and the business layer while retrieving them. This is what I have come up with. Can anyone share some light on what can be improved here and if there is another best way to implement this

[image]